# multidimensional Lists<T>?

Tags: c#, list, multidimensional-array

Until now I used multidimensional arrays `int[,] numbers = new int[3, 2] { {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};` but now I need something dynamic like list. Is there such a thing as multidimensional lists? I want to create something like a table with 4 columns. The 4th column should be a 10sec timer and when the 10seconds pass and column 2 and 3 on the specific line are not filled the whole line should be deleted from the list.

Comment: You could always create a `List<List<int>>`.

Comment: If I were you I would really try to show what I really want to do. It seems a little bit weird what you are doing.

Comment: To me it sounds like you don't want a true multidimensional list, but a single dimensional list with complex rows.

Comment: And the last column shouldn't be a timer, but a `DateTime` that contains either the creation time or the scheduled deletion time. (And use UTC times, not local times)

Answer (score 7):

In .NET 4 you could create a list of [tuples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
class Foo{
    public int Col1 { get;set; }
    public int Col2 { get;set; }
    public int Col3 { get;set; }
    public int Col4 { get;set; }
}
```

and `List<Foo>`

Comment: Yes, he did not mention what he was targeting

Comment: Probably the cleanest since you can choose meaningful names for the columns.

Answer (score 3):

what you want is `List< List< yourtype > >`

this will give you what you want:

```
List< List<int> > lst = new List< List< int > >;
lst.Add( new List<int>() );
lst[0].Add( 23 );
lst[0][0] == 23;
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you create a class that encapsulates what you said a single "line" in your list should do. It will give your code that much more expressiveness and be far more readable, which is the core trait of any good code.

So in the end you will have `List<YourSpecificClass>`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a list that contains list like:

```
var multiList = new List<List<int>>();
```

After reading through your question again I don't think this is what you want. My guess is that you want something like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public int? Col1 { get; set; }
    public int? Col2 { get; set; }
    public int? Col3 { get; set; }
    private Timer Timer { get; set; }
    public List<Item> ParentList { get; set; }

    public Item()
    {
        Timer = new Timer();
        Timer.Callback += TimerCallBack();
        // Set timer timeout
        // start timer
    }

    public void AddToList(List<Item> parentList)
    {
        parentList.Add(this);
        ParentList = parentList;
    }

    public void TimerCallBack() 
    {
        if(!Col3.HasValue || !Col2.HasValue)
        {
            ParentList.Remove(this);
        }
    }
}
....
var list = new List<Item>();
var item = new Item { /*Set your properties */  };
item.AddToList(list);
```

That should get you started. You can read about the `Timer` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your application.  You could use `List<List<int>>`, for instance, and add new items thusly:

```
myList.Add(new List<int> { 0, 0, 0, 0 });
```

It sounds from your last comment that you're going to be applying specific logic to the items in this list, which suggests the possibility that you should create a class for your items, e.g.

```
public class Item
{
   public int Col1 { get; set; }
   public int Col2 { get; set; }
   public int Col3 { get; set; }
   public int Col4 { get; set; }

   public bool CanRemove { get { return Col2==0 && Col3 == 0 && Col4 == 0; } }
```

and then create a `List<Item>`.  Then you can remove entries from it via:

```
var toRemove = myList.Where(x => x.CanRemove).ToList();
foreach (Item it in toRemove)
{
   myList.Remove(it);
}
```